# Existe-t-il des mots regroupant Oncle/Tante, Cousin/Cousine, Neveux/Nièces, etc

Tags: registre-familier, genre-biologique

Je suis sur un projet de généalogie et je me demandais s'il existait des termes génériques permettant de regrouper les deux sexes dans une relation familiale. Par exemple :

- Parents = Père ou mère
- Fratrie = Frère ou soeur
- Grand-Parents = Grand-père ou grand-mère
- ??? = Oncle ou tante
- ??? = Cousin ou cousine

Il est très possible que la langue française n'ait pas de termes génériques pour ces liens, mais je pose tout de même la question.

Merci :)

Answer (score 3):

Étant donné que je ne peux commenter qu'à partir de 50 de réputation, je fais une réponse qui n'en est pas une.

Pour frère et soeur, l'un des mots "génériques" est adelphe. Il est un peu démodé, mais à exactement le sens voulu.

Comment: Il me semble que ça ne définit que des frères

Comment: Initialement, peut-être, mais il a pris le sens de frères et soeurs [comme indiqué dans le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/adelphe#Nom_commun) ou sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne#Anglais) comme terme épicène (qui inclut les hommes et les femmes). Après ça reste un mot peu usité, mais intéressant à connaître.

Answer (score 0):

Pour les cousins/cousines je connais le terme "cousinage"

EDIT: en anthropologie, le terme "avunculat" est utilisé pour décrire le relation entre un oncle/tante et un neveu/nièce !

Comment: J'ai cru voir qu'avunculat c'est spécifiquement un oncle maternel.  La définition aurait changée?